# Is it possible to replace PHP 'logic' with merging 2 SQL queries (subquery would have dependencies to origin query)

Tags: mysql

i have a table which is called channel_user_mm.
I try to select  one special row with just one MySQL statement.

Here is a SQL fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cef86/4/0

There are 2 sepereate SQL statements which are in combination with PHP a "standard way" to figure it out:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    local
FROM  
    `channel_user_mm` 
WHERE 
    `foreign` = 2
        OR  
    `foreign` = 3
```

This query delivers a bunch of channel id's. Now i itaerate in PHP and test it with the query below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    COUNT(*) items
FROM  
    `channel_user_mm` 
WHERE  
    `local` = 12
```

I'm wondering if it is possible to compress this both to one query. I tried it with a subquery.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    local
FROM  
    `channel_user_mm` 
WHERE
    (   
        `foreign` = 2
            OR  
        `foreign` = 3
    )
        AND
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            COUNT(*) items
        FROM  
            `channel_user_mm` 
        WHERE  
            `local` = 12
    ) <= 2
```

I need a channel id in the subquery. I have no idea how to solve this issue atm.

So there are two questions in my head.

- Is it possible to merge both queries to one?
- How will it look?

I hope someone of you is able to help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT c.local, COUNT(*) items
FROM  `channel_user_mm` c
GROUP BY c.local 
WHERE `foreign` in (2, 3);
```

As I think about it, you seem to want the counts for "local" where at least one of the rows has a value of 2 or 3 for `foreign`.  This query may do what you want:

```
SELECT c.local, COUNT(*) items
FROM  `channel_user_mm` c 
GROUP BY c.local
HAVING max(`foreign` in (2, 3)) > 0;
```

Note:  `foreign` is a bad name for a column because it is a SQL reserved word.

Comment: Thanks for the advice with the reserved word.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.
I forgot something to say, sorry.

At the moment i want get a result which just has two elements in relation.
E.g. the elements with the value 13 in column local have a count of 3. I just want a count of 2 (local = 12)